# How can I copy data records between two instances of an SQLServer database

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, copy

I need to programmatically (ADO.Net) copy records from a table in one database to a table in another database on a different server.
This is very similar to ["How can I copy data records between two instances of an SQLServer database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153988/) except that I am not allowed to create a link to the destination server so the accepted answer to that question won't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it. Thanks to the other respondants for the inspiration. The code that builds the mappings is not necessary if the schemas of the two tables are identical.

```
public void CopyTables(string sourceConnectionString, string destConnectionString)
{
        string sql = "Select * From SourceTable";
        using (SqlConnection sourceConn = new SqlConnection(sourceConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand sourceCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, sourceConn)) {
            sourceConn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = sourceCmd.ExecuteReader())
            using (SqlBulkCopy copier = new SqlBulkCopy(destConnectionString)) {
                copier.DestinationTableName = "DestinationTable";
                copier.BulkCopyTimeout = 300;

                DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();
                copier.ColumnMappings.Clear();
                foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows) {
                    copier.ColumnMappings.Add(row["ColumnName"].ToString(), row["ColumnName"].ToString());
                }

                copier.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class

Answer (score 0):

The SqlBulkCopy class suggested by santiiii is very efficient but it creates a non-logged operation.  I had to do this once but my target database participated in replication, so I needed the operation to be fully logged.  What I essentially ended up doing was selecting a dataset from the source database .

```
Select * from SourceDatabaseTable where (some clause to get the right records)
```

Then  creating an empty dataset from the destination table with this statement

```
Select * from DestinationDatabaseTable where 1<>1
```

Then I had two datasets.  The first with the records I wanted to copy and the second that is empty.  Next I just did a nested foreach loop to copy the records from one dataset to the other.  Here is the Pseudocode for the core copy function:

```
foreach(datarow sourcedr in sourcetable)
{
   datarow destdr = destdatatable.createrow();
   foreach(datacolumn in sourcedatatable)
   {
      destdr[datacolumn]=Sourcedr[datacolum];
   }
}
```

Lastly, I just used a data adapter to submit the changes on the destination database.