# C# copy data between databases

Tags: c#, database, copy

What is the fastest method for copying data between databases in c#?
I want to create c# database procedure than accepts query string as parameter and inserts data to another database (sql query and destination table will have the same columns).

I use SQLBulkCopy right now but causes some problems.

Comment: can you tell us what problems? because i wrote such project and used SQLBulkCopy . it works great.

Comment: "causes some problems" - what problems? that approach is pretty good, so if you explain the problem maybe we can fix that

Comment: "I use SQLBulkCopy right now but causes some problems." - Really? and what might they be? (Crystal ball is broken)

Comment: Have you tried to backup the DB and restore it to the second DB? or ar the DB systems different?

Comment: The problem is when 2 users try to execute procedure in the same time the procedure crashes and it dose not work until next dll deployment (restart does not help).

Comment: Backup and restore wont help. I need to copy data automatically every 30 min

Comment: sounds like a job for replication

Answer (score 0):

I know you've asked about C# in your post, but you might want to consider a couple of other methods, using the stored procedure you are about to create. All of the below would be in the stored procedure itself.

Have you considered a T-SQL approach using OPENROWSET() That way, you never have to pull the data back over to C# and send it back over to SQL server. You will find some recommendations from [Microsoft here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190923.aspx)
and here is [the specific link using OPENROWSET()](http://jasonhaley.com/blog/post/2004/03/23/Using-OPENROWSET-for-moving-data-from-SQL-Server-to-SQL-Server.aspx)

If you want to use C# still, you can also use SSIS, which has an ability to copy data in bulk mode between servers, and you can call it from C# using the appropriate package you'd have to create (visual workflow). Please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153988/how-can-i-copy-data-records-between-two-instances-of-an-sqlserver-database) for details.